# copy range values into variant using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in a macro but when I run it, it only copies the value from cell B2 rather than the entire range of values from B2:D2 as I have specified in line 5 of the below code.

```
Sub copying()
Dim calval as variant
With worksheets("sheet1")
Set calval=.Cells(Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Offset(2,3)
calval.value=Range("B2:D2").Value 'copy range of values
End With
End Sub
```

This is the data in cells B2:D2

```
21.7 21.3 22.4
```

Can someone please tell me how to get calval to be assigned the full range of values from B2:D2, rather than just the value in B2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few problems here. Firstly when copying to variants, they are not objects so you don't need to use set.  They also don't have ranges as they variables.  You also need to copy the value to a variant before you can set it to the output range so the order is a little off.  The following code will work:

```
Sub Copying()
    Dim calval as Variant

    'Read it in from the worksheet
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        calval=.Range("B2:D2").value

        'Set it back to the dsired range using the bounds of the variant instead of hardcoding.
       .Range(.Cells(Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Offset(2,3), .Cells(Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Offset(1 + UBound(calval, 1), 2 + UBound(calval, 2))).Value = calval
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: but using the last line of your code doesn't allow me to achieve what I have in line 4 of my code where I have the offset. I cannot assign to range `B3:D3` the contents of calval.

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to copy into the variable with the `.Offset(2,3)` line and paste into B2:D2?  I'll edit for you

Comment: the reverse, copying from B2:D2 and offseting by 2,3 to put the values of B2:D2 into it, i.e. into E4:G4. with my code it is only copying contents of B2 into E4

Comment: If you are using the cursor to see it's value by hovering the mouse above it, you won't see anything because it's value is an array.  On calval in the code, right click and 'Add Watch' which will show you the values of the array.  If your worksheet has values in B2:D2 line 4 will copy those values to calval

Comment: aha, got it. so if i wanted to change the offset to 1,0, would I rewrite line 4 as: `.Range(.Cells(Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0), .Cells(Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Offset(0 + UBound(calval, 1), 0)).Value = calval`

Comment: Yeah, pretty much, be careful not to get your code so complicated to read! It might be better to break it down a bit (ie set the output cell as a range and then go from there), its also easier to debug that way.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you have accepted an answer, here is another method to achieve what you need: Using `WorkSheetFunction.Transpose` method.

```
Dim calval as Variant
'--- Range("B2:D2").Value

calval = WorkSheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("B2:D2").Value)
```

You are free to use, `offset`, `resize` according to your needs.
e.g. expand your range up to `B12`

```
calval = WorkSheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(1).Range("B2:D2").Resize(10).Value)
```

Comment: @user1155299 if you are interested, take a look at this as well ;)