# Use a range in array elements but it returns nothing

Tags: excel, vba

I am running into some issues while using VBA Array in 'Filter' function. I am trying to use a range in array elements but it returns nothing

```
Sub newfilter()

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim rng As Variant
Sheet3.Activate
Set rng = Range("B2:B350")
arr = Array("rng")

Sheet2.Range("A1").AutoFilter _
    Field:=3, _
    Criteria1:=arr(), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

I tried to use vba array filter but its return nothing. i am not strong in macros. required correct set of codes.

Comment: `Array("rng")` creates a string array with 1 element that is not the `rng` variable. I do not think that's what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428718/8422953

Comment: Still am confused don't know how to code pls help in detail while running it shows as automation error.

Comment: Dim rng As Range
Sheet3.Activate
Set rng = Range("B2:B350")
arr = Array(rng)
some minor corrections there..... You really want to set 349 possible filter values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868332/vba-autofilter-using-an-array-ignore-criteria-if-it-is-not-in-the-filtered-lis